# Main navigation item not as wide as sub-menu item

Tags: html, css, navigation, width, submenu

this is what the problem looks like: http://parnu.webweaver.ee/

The sub-menu words are too long and it all looks weird. How can I fix that? This is my CSS:

```
/*navigation styles
*/
nav
{
    background: url(../images/bg_footer.png);
}

nav#mainNav ul, nav#mainNav ul li
{
    margin: 0px;
}

nav#mainNav ul li
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

nav#mainNav ul li a
{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 49px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    color: rgb(245,233,227);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
}

nav#mainNav ul li a:hover
{
    border-bottom: none;
    background: rgb(186,230,78);
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*sub menu*/
nav#mainNav ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background: url(../images/bg_footer.png);
    min-width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

nav#mainNav ul ul li
{
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: 100%;
}

nav#mainNav ul ul li a
{
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

I've been messing with this problem for hours. Please help me with this issue.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the menu "buttons" to be the same width as the drop-down parts, right?

The problem is that the drop-down `ul` is positioned absolutely, so the parent `li` doesn't take into account its dimensions.

Currently you're doing this:

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">Dropdown Menu Header</a>
            <ul style="display:block; position:absolute;">
                <li>Dropdown Item 1</li>
                <li>Dropdown Item 2</li>
                <li>Dropdown Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of using an unordered list for the dropdown, use a definition list (`dl`). This has "definition title" (`dt`) tags which you can use for the dropdown menu header, and "definition definition" (`dd`) tags which you can use for the dropdown menu items.

This way, the menu header is *inside* the same element as the menu items. Position the <`dd`> *relatively* instead of absolutely, and don't position the `dt` or `dd` tags at all. Then the menu header and menu items will be the same width, and the parent `li` will expand according to their width.

Like this:

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <dl style="display:block; position:relative;">
                <dt>Dropdown Menu Header</dt>
                <dd>Dropdown Item 1</dd>
                <dd>Dropdown Item 2</dd>
                <dd>Dropdown Item 3</dd>
            </dl>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```